# Can a metal pipe shield wiring against EMP during a nearby lightning strike?

Tags: shielding, lightning

I have a building which regularly experiences nearby lightning strikes. The backup diesel generator is located 10 meters away from the building. Can induced currents from the EMP be reduced within the wires connecting the building to the generator, if they were made to run through a grounded metal pipe? The pipe will run above ground.

Comment: I think the EMP is also induced into the ground. Once my home was struck by EMP, the first strike opened the main circuit breaker, the next blinked all the high efficiency lights in the house, even with switches and circuit breakers open.

Comment: Not sure you can do anything useful, there's a narrow margin between "close enough to cause trouble" and "so close, nothing can save you". What is the _symptom_ of strikes you are trying to prevent?

Comment: @JohnU, the symptom manifests itself in the form of a dead generator control panel. However, there is no noticeable damage to the electronics. The panel is within the building and connected by external wiring to the genset.

Comment: What is "dead" then - is it some sort of cutoff (RCD / fuse) in the panel, control electronics blown, circuit shutdown, exploded... there could be anything in a "control panel" depending on the generator.

Comment: This may not be EMP so much as a step voltage increase of the ground itself. When the local ground becomes a few thousand volts for a microsecond, most attempts to engineer around that become frustrated. But that's not a near strike, that's usually a direct hit or a power line laying nearby.

Comment: @Sean, no issues with the ground. All the other electronics on the site such as UPS, switches, routers and microwave base stations continue to operate normally during and after the strike. The issue lies solely between the generator outside the building and the control panel found within the building.  I was wondering whether a grounded metal pipe enclosure would act similar to the MuMetal shielding found at aluminium plants and in addition protect against electric flux.

Comment: It might very well, depending on specific conditions. What exactly does it take to fix the issue after it happens?

Comment: Unfortunately, the generator line controller board needs to be replaced - i.e. replacing the microcontroller and associated circuitry. I was hoping someone might have a link to a lab test of some sort simulating a nearby lightning strike whilst at the same time measuring the magnetic and electrical flux  on equipment within the pipe casing. Been trying to Google it without luck.

Comment: The problem you are having may be due to inadequate signal isolation on the part of the controls manufacturer. Conjecture aside, I would have the board analyzed for failure mode before laying out cash for a modification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, in regards to your original post, yes - grounded metallic piping will act as a Faraday cage and can shield wiring and electronics from EMP. To be useful, the whole system must be encased, which may be practical or not. Likely, a conduit could be run directly from the generator to the control panel/annunciator.

Watch out for other signal paths, though. Generators having wiring harnesses that would be impractical to encase, and may need shielded wiring.

As an aside, EMP damage has been assumed here, and may not actually be the case. I still urge that you have the board closely analyzed. Having to replace the board anyway, you might be able to get one with better isolation that isn't susceptible to the kind of failure the original board suffered.